# Why, conceptually, is the second moment sometimes handier than the first moment?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, variance

Sometimes $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ just seems handier than merely using $\mathbb{E}[|X|]$? Why?

I'll give an example. An exercise in our class was this: Let $(X_k)$ be a sequence of independent random variables with
$$ \mathbb{P}[X_k = k] = \mathbb{P}[X_k = -k] = \frac{1}{2k \log(k+1)}, \ \mathbb{P}[X_k = 0] = 1 - \frac{1}{k \log(k+1)}. $$ Show that $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n X_k \xrightarrow{\mathbb{P}} 0$.

One could aim to apply Chebyshev/Markov to get 
$$ \mathbb{P} \left[ \left|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n X_k \right| > \varepsilon \right] \leq \frac{\mathbb{E} \left[ \left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k \right|\right]}{\varepsilon}.$$ But this does not help too much (at least not immediately).

If we however instead bound it in $L^2$, then we can apply linearity of $\operatorname{Var}$, etc. and relatively quickly resolve this exercise.

I've seen this happen in several other occasions. So why is the second moment sometimes helpful - or better: when (and why!) is it more helpful? The variance describes different things than the expected value but e.g. in this case it's "just" the difference of $\mathbb{E}[|X|]$ and $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$.

Is it simply because $L^2$ is a Hilbert Space and hence naturally, everything is much better?

Comment: Yes, the fact that $L^2$ is a Hilbert Space---which is mostly just a fancy way of saying that variance is additive when things are independent---makes sums more amenable to it.

Comment: Wait, $L^2$ being a Hilbert Space is related to the additivity? I didn’t know that, wow. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Yeah in a Hilbert space, if $f$ and $g$ are orthogonal then $\| f + g \|^2 = \|f \|^2 + \| g \|^2$ (this is the Pythagorean theorem).  In the random variable side, let $X$ and $Y$ be mean-zero random variables.  Independence implies uncorrelation, so $\langle X, Y \rangle = E[X] E[Y] = 0$, so the two are orthogonal.  The pythagorean theorem then says that variance adds.

Comment: Ahhh, this is super nice. Great, thank you, that was a huge insight to me!